just_audio with headers does not working in Android
In just_audio package, when I use headers with setUrl, ex:
final duration = await player.setUrl('
    https://example.com/audio.m4a',
    headers: {'header1': 'value1', 'header2': 'value2'}
);

I get this exception in Android only:
PlayerException ((0) Source error)
How to solve this issue?
And help please.

https://example.com/bar.mp3 is not an audio file

I just edited the question and changed the example to an audio file :)

To be able to use headers in just_audio package, you must apply the setup here:
https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#platform-specific-configuration
